# BLE Device disconnect with Android device automatically. Android BLE

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-4.4-kitkat, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I'm using Android Nexus 7 to connect a device via Bluetooth Low Energy link. I'm able to connect the device, and stay connected if I don't do any communication with the device.

However, if I enable the notification of one specific characteristic by clicking a button, then the device would disconnect with the tablet after a few seconds' data transmission.

Does anyone know what might be the problem? Thank you very much!

Here's my code:

```
    public boolean setCharacteristicNotification(boolean enabled){

      if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
          Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
               return false;      
      }

      BluetoothGattService Service = mBluetoothGatt.getService(UUID_MY_SERVICE);
      if (Service == null) {
          Log.e(TAG, "service not found!");
          return false;
      }

      BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = Service.getCharacteristic(UUID_MY_CHARACTERISTIC);

      final int charaProp = characteristic.getProperties();

      if ((charaProp | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_NOTIFY) > 0) {
          mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, enabled);

            BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(
                    UUID.fromString(SampleGattAttributes.CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG));
            descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE); 

            mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);

          return true;
      }

    return false;

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Answered in a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [What is the appropriate action when the answer to a question is added to the question itself?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que) )

The OP wrote:

> I solved this problem today.
>
> Just change `descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);`
>
> to `descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_INDICATION_VALUE);`
>
> Follow Up:
>
> After I did some research and testing, I found that the automatically disconnection problem has something to do with the interference between Bluetooth and WIFI on Nexus 7. If I turned off the WIFI, then the disconnection problem of Bluetooth has gone. And this problem did not occur on Galaxy 3,4,5.

Comment: @Brain : Before apply this every characteristics will notifying continue some time and then it disconnect it self. after change this even single  characteristics not notify single time and disconnect sometime same.

Comment: @Brain : i have tried connecting with mac from android app. But its not connected, and status will be disconnected at every time. status code will be 133. But device will be paired.

Answer (score 0):

Problem: I was having same problem on Tesco Hudl 2, if i transmit some
 data soon as Bluetooth is connected, it  will disconnect.
 Solution: Wait for few
 seconds after connection, it seems to work okay.