# connecting issue with android ble

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

i have issue with ble getting disconnecting,
below is my code i changes it based on some answer earlier is used to get response which show data from ble device to my phone ,

but after code change i can not get data from device i think it has to do something with "ENABLE_INDICATION_VALUE" and "ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE"

can i call both at same time

```
public void setCharacteristicNotification(BluetoothGattCharacteristic bluetoothgattcharacteristic, boolean flag)
{
    if(mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null)
    {
        Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
    } else
    {
        mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(bluetoothgattcharacteristic, flag);
        BluetoothGattDescriptor bluetoothgattdescriptor = bluetoothgattcharacteristic.getDescriptor(UUID.fromString(SampleGattAttributes.CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG));
        if(bluetoothgattdescriptor != null)
        {       bluetoothgattdescriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
            mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(bluetoothgattdescriptor);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

later based on given stackoverflow question:

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676402/ble-device-disconnect-with-android-device-automatically-android-ble)

i changed below line

bluetoothgattdescriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);

to 
    bluetoothgattdescriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_INDICATION_VALUE);